# MySQL Query the sum of values based off int_id

Tags: mysql

Here is an example of my table.

```
int_id    ranking    prize
1         1          120
1         2          60
1         3          30
2         1          40
2         2          25
3         1          500
```

I'm trying to figure out how to take this table sum the prize monies of each event and list the int_id and total money. So it will look like this

```
int_id    total_money
1         210
2         65
3         500
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you need to use the aggregate function SUM, grouping by the int_id:

```
SELECT int_id, sum(prize) as total_money
from tablename
GROUP BY int_id
```